# Custom Android button with selector doesn't load bakground

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have this custom Android button in `drawable` folder with a selector to load a different image for the clicked buttons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_blue_click" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_blue_unclick"/>
</selector>
```

Sometimes work fine, others times doesn't show the background of the button.

I have tried also to add the line

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_blue_unclick" android:state_pressed="false"/>
```

(Because the PNG image in background isn't load when the button is unclicked.)

I cannot figure what is the cause of this strange issue.

Comment: "others times doesn't show the background of the button", are you refering to bt_blue_unclick?

Comment: yes,sometimes the background unclicked isn't showed

Comment: the xml code you posted above looks fine. Can you post the part where you are using the selector?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_blue_click" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_blue_unclick"/>

</selector>
```

its working well in my case..!